# Extract folder name only from zip archive

Tags: php, zip

I have created a PHP script that uploads file and extract it and get folder name inside the zip and insert its name and path into db. However it doesn't extract the folder name from zip archive and doesn't gets path name like I want. It extracts all direcotories and file names I just want directory names. Lets say I have zip file called `abc.zip` and it contains folders like this
`a ->b->c`

`ab ->bc`

 What I want is to be able to get only parnet directory names like a and b currently it gets all directory names and file names.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($filen);
$zip->extractTo($path);
$zip->close();

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($filen) === true) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
        $db->con->query("Insert into files (rand) values ('$filename')");
    }                  
    $zip->close();                  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$fileinfo = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$db->con->query("Insert into files (rand) values ('$fileinfo')");
```

Comment: Can you tell where I define the `PATHINFO_DIRNAME`?

Comment: `PATHINFO_DIRNAME` is a parameter for pathinfo. See here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: That doesn't works it only inserts dot in the database instead of folder name?

Comment: Then that means that the file isn't in a subfolder.

Comment: no I just uploaded a zip file called `n.zip` which contains a folder called `n` inside it there is another folder which I don't want to be listed and an html file. Update when I changed filename to full path then it just inserted the file path in database.